# Twilio Conversations + React Native, notifications do not working on IOS (firebase)

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, twilio, twilio-conversations

does somebody implements push notifications on twilio conversations with react native and firebase? Notifications work well on android and config on ios is also fine (cloud messages from firebase console came). Is it possible to use ios with firebase to twilio notifications at all? In twilio documentation there is only ios/web/android and nothing is told about react native. Maybe somebody had the same problem.

Comment: While Twilio Conversations doesn't officially support React Native, it does work and the notifications should work too. You are going to have to share more details in order to get people to help debug though.

Comment: Do you know if notifications on ios also uses firebase? I mean on android it is twilio->firebase=>our_app on ios config there is nothing told about fcm, and only apn setup is shown but every time when I was doing notifications on ios in react native, I also use firebase and I don't have idea how am I going to made this in twilio. twilio->apn->firebase->app or just twilio->apn->app

Comment: It's my understanding that you can [set up FCM to deliver notifications to iOS applications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client). You can also send them directly with APNs. If Twilio is asking for APNs settings in order to send notifications, then you should fill them in and the notifications will go Twilio -> APNS -> app.